# Using an imported type in JSDoc @typedef

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm trying to reduce duplication in specifying my imported types as follows but I'm getting an error

```js
/**
@typedef {import("../types/util")} util
@typedef {util.mapBehaviors} mapBehaviors
... lots of other typedefs based on util
*/
```

```
'util' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.
```

It's weird because expanding the import explicitly works:

```js
/**
@typedef {import("../types/util").mapBehaviors} mapBehaviors
... lots of other typedefs
*/
```

How can I use `@typedef` with an alias of an import?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you are only exporting `interface` or `type` from your `.d.ts` file and not `function` or `const`.

This will work:

```js
/**
@typedef {import("../types/types").util} util
@typedef {util["mapBehaviors"]} mapBehaviors
...
*/
```

but only if in `util.d.ts` you have

```js
export function mapBehaviors(tags: string[] | Behavior[], table: Behaviors): Behavior[]
...
```

instead of

```js
export interface mapBehaviors {
  (tags: string[] | Behavior[], table: Behaviors): Behavior[]
}
```

Comment: Could you give more details about the above statement(This can happen if you are only exporting interface or type from your .d.ts file and not function or const)?